# Adding Whitespace in Middle of Sentence

Tags: html, css, format, whitespace, indentation

In HTML5, how do you skip 5 spaces in a `<div>`?  For example, how do you do this:

"Drumroll... [5 spaces] Something!"

`<div>Drumroll... [5 spaces] Something!</div>` just outputs "Drumroll... Something!"

There does not seem to be any tags such as `<indent>` that I have found to indent in the middle of a sentence.

`&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp` works, but is there a more efficient way?  Such as...

```
<skip 10px></skip>
```

Specifically, I am looking for the solution to insert exactly 1,000 spaces easily, for example.

Comment: Can you use 5 &nbsp; characters?

Comment: Yes I can, sorry I should have been more clear.  Looking for something more efficient than typing that over and over.

Comment: Not sure there is, but hopefully someone chimes in.   Traditionally, extra spaces in HTML are ignored in text

Comment: The alternatives I see are either using CSS (either with `margin`/`padding` like MrVimes' answer, or with `:before`/`:after` and `content` and only typing the numerous `&nbsp;`s out once in the value of `content`), using JavaScript to insert the characters (CSS would be vastly preferable to JS), or doing something server-side if that's an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not perfectly five spaces, and I'm not sure if there's a way to do it without using five consecutive `&nbsp;`s, but this will allow you to add a specifiable amount of space inline.

```
<p>Drumroll...<span style="margin-left:50px;"></span>something</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5drHj/1/

Another option might be to use the [`<pre>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) tag...

```
<pre>Drumroll...     something</pre>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5drHj/2/

If you do decide to use consecutive `&nbsp;` you could use a javascript loop (or php loop for server side construction) to add the 1000 `&nbsp;`s

**Edit:** At the risk of losing my tick, I'd like to point out that the answer given by @vals is a third option, and perhaps the most elegant of the three.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such element in HTML. Long ago, there was the nonstandard `<spacer>` tag, but it was abandoned. You are supposed to use CSS for things like this. Wrap some preceding text in a `<span>` element and set `padding-left: 1.25em` on it. Tune the value as needed. The width of a space depends on font but is on the average around `0.25em`.

Answer (score 1):

The question that you pose in the first half of the question (How to insert spaces easily),  is achieved with the property:

```
white-space: pre;
```

It means that your text is pre-formatted, and the white spaces should stay as they are. Then just insert those spaces.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/8ZT9c/)

If you want to insert 1000 spaces, then we are talking probably about alignment, and there is a huge amount of posibilities. (padding specified in em being the most obvious), but you should then give more details of your situation.